# Building a bot with Smooch

Tags: smooch

I'm a first time user on Smooch. Can the Smooch platform itself be used to build a bot? In other words, can I define an intent/flow on Smooch platform itself or does it simply connect to other services?

Answer (score 1):

> can I define an intent/flow on Smooch platform itself or does it simply connect to other services?

The latter, but I can add some detail. The Smooch platform itself isn't a bot framework, but it's a great interface to connect your bot to in order to bring your bot to numerous channels. Once your bot integrates with Smooch, it works with all channels that Smooch supports, including native SDKs.

If you're looking for a more ready-made bot framework, but you also want your bot to have the wide channel presence that Smooch offers, here are some bot platforms that have integrated with Smooch:

https://app.smooch.io/integrations/categories/bot-platform

If you want to implement a bot that integrates directly with Smooch APIs, I believe special offerings for that are in the works, and you can reach out from here:

https://smooch.io/bots